# How to load remote Maxima script?

Tags: webserver, maxima

I've written formula snippets containing user-defined functions (for example `func-name(x,n):=x^2+x^3/n)`.
Now, I would like to share them with my colleagues.

What I am planning to do;

- store snippet as `.mac` files
- store files on https webserver

My question is, once the `.mac` files are on server, how can we access them remotely using Maxima?

Comment: There isn't a well-defined way to do that, although there may exist parts of it. My advice is to post a message to the Maxima mailing list about it. See: https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/lists/maxima-discuss You might want to say more about what you are doing and what you hope to achieve.

Comment: By the way, have you considered using a service like pastebin to store snippets? or you could create a project on Github and store them there.